# Probability density calculation question

Tags: electric-current, probability, differentiation, density

Here is a part of probability density prove,[image]

I can't understand why the second term of the last sequence was changed from  psi* del^2 psi to psi del^2 psi*.

http://bado-shanai.net/Map%20of%20Physics/mopProbDensity.htm

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) please provide a bit of context the next time - it makes it easier to answer ;)

Comment: They just reorder the terms and cancel the terms with potential energy.

Comment: @ErikJörgenfelt I've known that if you want to reorder some operators with a function, it should be commute each other... or? Derivative operator don't have directional difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us go through this
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Psi^*\Psi\right) &= \left(\frac{-i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi^* - \frac{U}{i\hbar}\Psi^*\right)\Psi + \Psi^*\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi + \frac{U}{i\hbar}\right).
\end{align}
The terms involving the potential energy cancel leaving:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Psi^*\Psi\right) = \left(\frac{-i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi^*\right)\Psi + \Psi^*\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi\right).
\end{align}
Each expression within paranthesis is *not* an operator: it is an operator acting on a state, producing a new state. The states are represented by functions, and multiplication of functions commute. Therefore we can write it as
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Psi^*\Psi\right) &= \Psi\left(\frac{-i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi^*\right) + \Psi^*\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi\right) \\
&=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left(\Psi\nabla^2\Psi^* + \Psi^*\nabla^2\Psi\right) \\
&= \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left(\Psi^*\nabla^2\Psi + \Psi\nabla^2\Psi^*\right).
\end{align}